# Access a local variable inside a method

Tags: ruby

Following is the sample code what I am trying to do..

```
debug = false
debug_file = "debug.txt"
terminate_tool

def terminate_tool
  info_string = "Terminating tool execution ...\n"
  print info_string
  File.open(debug_file, "a") { |file| file.print info_string } if debug
end
```

Here, how can i access the variables outside method inside and how can i declare a prototype of method because i want its definition to write at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using a variable outside the method by using an instance variable.

```
def terminate_tool
  p @debug_file # "debug.txt"
end

@debug_file = "debug.txt"    
terminate_tool
```

I would recommend passing it through to the method though.

```
def terminate_tool(debug_file)
  p debug_file # "debug.txt"
end

terminate_tool("debug.txt")
```

I am not really sure what your end goal is given your minimal code sample.  However reading about procs,  blocks and lambdas may help.  http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.html

As an aside, the instance variable will not pass through to instances of a class.

```
def terminate_tool
  p @debug_file # "debug.txt"
end

class A
  def foo
    p @debug_file # nil
  end
end

@debug_file = "debug.txt"
terminate_tool

a = A.new
a.foo
```